# Работа с файлами в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно пройтись по всем файлам в папке, не используя лист с именами всех папок?

Т.е. нужен примерно такой код

```
QFile getFile () {
    while (текущий_элемент != последний) {
        tmp = текущий_элемент;
        ++текущий_элемент;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш псевдокод будет всегда возвращать первый файл

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `QDirIterator`

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
QDir dir(_baseDir);

QStringList mask;
mask << "[a-zA-Z]*";
QStringList fileList = dir.entryList(mask, QDir::Files);

for (auto file : fileList) {
    qDebug() << "file:" << dir.absoluteFilePath(file);
    //TODO: place your code here
}
```

в данном примере можно еще и задать фильтр. (Здесь используется синтаксис C++11, но можно использовать и "классическое" иттерирование (с помощью `QStringListIterator`))